# Displaying ModelState Errors with AngularJS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

**Update:**

The one you have in your sample link you posted its pretty simple the way the error message is rendering but if you look at mine show below its bit different then what you had and I have `data.Errors=>ErrorId>>Message`

[image]

**Update END**

I'm trying to show ModelState errors (like ValidationSummary) in ASP.NET MVC using AngularJS.

I'm unable to display the error messages that I'm getting from  `data.Errors`

Here is my code in AngularJS:

```
$scope.AddUser = function ()
{
    $http.post('adduser', $scope.User).success(function (data, status, headers, config)
    {
        $scope.message = '';
        $scope.errors = [];

        if (data.success === false) {
            $scope.errors = [];
            $scope.errors = data.errors;
        }
        else {
            $scope.message('Successfully Added ' + $scope.User.UserName + '!');
            $scope.user = {};
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config)
    {
        $scope.errors = [];
        $scope.errors = data.errors;
        $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
    }); 
}
```

//html code:

```
 <form name="AddUsr" ng-submit="AddUser()">
            <div class="error">{{message}}</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column third">User Name</div>
                <div class="column two-thirds"><input ng-model="User.UserName" required /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column third">Email</div>
                <div class="column two-thirds"><input ng-model="User.Email" required /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column full"><input type="submit" value="Add User" /></div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li id="errorMessages" class="error" data-ng-repeat="error in errors">{{error}}</li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a typo and you're doing $scope.errors = data.Errors;

Your repeater should probably be:

```
<ul>
   <li id="errorMessages" class="error" data-ng-repeat="error in errors">{{error[0].Message}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: certainly that's typo from my end when I was typing

Comment: Its not displaying any error message after I update your code

Comment: @AbuHamzah then you'll need to provide more troubleshooting info as this seems to work http://plnkr.co/edit/01ia64S99tndLlYL7oE4?p=preview

Comment: I have updated my question with more troubleshooting information.

Comment: @AbuHamzah I've updated the plunker and the answer. You just need to ensure that your repeater actually follows the pattern of the API. However I would modify the API as that structure seems ridiculously complicated

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, your controller action should doing something like this to return the .success and .errors via JSON when the model state is invalid. Is it doing this?

```
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
            // Your logic here ...
            // ...

            // return true if successfull
           return Json(new { success = true});    
      }
      return Json(new
      {
          success = false,
          errors = ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(k => ModelState[k].Errors)
                          .Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
      });
```

Comment: as you see the code, it is returning the error messages my question is more towards displaying the error message on the UI

Answer (score 0):

in order to show the ModelState error try accessing the ModelState object that should be returned as a property on the error.

```
<ul>
    <li id="errorMessages" class="error" data-ng-repeat="error in errors">
        {{error[0].ModelState[Object.keys(error[0].ModelState)[0]]}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

But, you must make sure that your back end is returning 'ModelState' in its response.  Your 'error' object has a 'Message' property but it should also have a 'ModelState' property there also.